# ndb allocate_ids with parent

Tags: python, google-app-engine

There are quite a few questions related to Ndb `allocate_ids()` which seems to be a fuzzy area in Ndb, but I found this issue handled nowhere.

When using a parent/child hierarchy, `ids` should be unique *for a given parent key*, so you may create

```
entity_1 = MyEntity(parent=my_parent_key_1, id=23)    
entity_2 = MyEntity(parent=my_parent_key_2, id=23)
```

Now when you need to allocate ids for explicit assignment, the static function `MyEntity.allocate_ids()` takes a parent as argument.   So you would assume that `allocate_ids()` with a parent argument reserves a range of ids for the given parent, not *for any parent*.

However:

```
MyEntity.allocate_ids(max=1000, parent=ndb.Key(MyParentEntity, 'aaa'))
```

returns ̀`(1L, 1000L)`.  The first 1000 ids are allocated.  Now run:

```
MyEntity.allocate_ids(max=1000, parent=ndb.Key(MyParentEntity, 'bbb'))
```

returns `(1001L, 1000L)`, which means the first available id is 1001L, and nothing new was allocated, although the parent key was different.

Now run:

```
MyEntity.allocate_ids(max=2000, parent=ndb.Key(MyParentEntity, 'ccc'))
```

returns `(1001L, 2000L)`, which means ids from 1001 to 2000 were allocated.

Thus it would seem `allocate_ids` is in fact independent of parent key.  And you may wonder why pass the parent_key as argument then.

Anyone has an explanation for this, or could point to documentation related to this strange behavior ?

And a related question: is there a way to know what id range (or ranges) has been reserved by passed calls to `allocate_ids()` ?

Comment: Just found out that it's worse than I imagined:  the id ranges are allocated for the whole Ndb database, not for a given entity.   From earlier example, if I later do a `MyOtherEntity.allocate_ids(100)`, I get (2001L, 2100L).  Even though it's for another entity, the allocated range follows on the previously allocated ranges.   Therefore, you cannot have 2 distinct entity kinds, each using user-defined allocated ids say from 1 to 1000, and leaving Ndb to assign automatic ids outside this range.  Instead, the first entity will get 1 to 1000, the next entity will get 1001 to 2000.

Comment: I think your expecting too much see @daniel answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this matters. The only purpose of allocate_ids is to ensure that GAE does not automatically give an entity certain ID values if you don't define a full key yourself. It doesn't do anything else; in particular, it doesn't impose any restrictions on what you do with those IDs. There's certainly nothing to stop you, contrary to what you say in the comment, using the same allocated ID value for two distinct entity kinds.

Comment: What matters really is that the documentation is potentially misleading, but you are right:  we can live with that, once we know how it works.   Having `allocate_ids()` a method of entity model classes really suggests we are allocating ids _for this class_.   And similarly, accepting a parent key argument really suggests we are allocating ids _for this parent_.  Both statements are not correct however, and it's worth knowing that.    I'll take the answer, nonetheless, since none better is likely to arise.  Thank you.